# Django vs Flutter for multiple requests

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart

I need to create a web solution that will have simultaneous real-time updates of a lot of data..
And I'm in doubt between using Flutter Web or Django..

I would like to know which of these should be more performant, and the reasons.. If a separate backend and frontend solution would be better, or if to do everything together (django)..

In terms of performance.. The pros and cons

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a front-end solution only using which you can develop Apps
for Web/Android/IOS/Windows and more platform from same codebase, You can consume any kind of web services using Flutter(Rest/SOAP/Websocket/GraphQl).
separate backend and frontend would lead to develop more decoupled and scalable systems.

If your target is only web solution then it's better to go with Django (web framework).